# Comparing some parts of a file

Tags: java

I have a question that has been eluding me for the whole day. I want to read part of a file and compare it to other parts of same file. if I can get some kind of logic on how to collect the first set of lines and compare it with the other sets and then move to the next set and compare with the remaining until I compare every set with each other..

what I want to accomplish is this read the first 3 lines skip the next compare it with the next 3 line, skip the next and compare it with the next 3 line and after that move to the 2nd 3 lines and compare that with the 3rd set and 4th set and so on. So what am trying to do is something like

```
 for{ int i=0; i < file.lenght; i++

     for {int j=0; j=i+1; i++{

   }}
```

but for a txt file

SAMPLE FILE

```
 this is the way to go
 this is not really it
 what did they say it was
 laughing hahahahahahahaa
 are we on the right path
 this is not really it
 what did they say it was
 smiling hahahahahahahaha
 they are way behind 
 tell me how to get therr
 home here we come
 hahahahahahahaha they laught
 are we on the right path
 this is not really it
 what did they say it was
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying with words, kind of - could you illustrate the cycles of file reduction you're going through?

Comment: the file is a log file and it has sections that say start and some out put and it says end, it continues in that format till the end of the file. All I want to do is check for duplicate so I have to compare all the out puts in between start and end with each other until the end of the file to make sure there are no duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file fits in memory, I would read all lines into a List with Files.readAllLines(path,charset)  (Java 7) and then would do the comparisons on the List

If files is too big then create a method

```
List<String> readLines(Scanner sc, int nLines) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i++) {
        list.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    return list;
}
```

and use it to read / skip parts of the file

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("path"));
List<String> list1 = readLines(sc, 3);
readLines(sc, 1);
List<String> list2 = readLines(sc, 3);
boolean res = list1.equals(list2)
```

Comment: the file will be too but to read all to memory is there any other way I can go about it?

Comment: that is very helpfull but going through the file I found out they are not all 3 lines before the skip, some have 4 and some are 6 line before I get to skip any ideas